# Nested Loops in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, loops, qualtrics

I am currently using loop and merge in a Qualtrics survey, and I want to add a nested loop inside of the current loop. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is there a link to what you have done till now?

Comment: Like to the survey itself or the survey builder? I wasn't aware you can link survey builder to other people if you mean the former.

Here's a link to a simple test survey using loop & merge.
https://goo.gl/t9iK0Q

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to nest loops. A loop & merge block is the only type of loop in Qualtrics and you can't put a block within another block.

You can execute a block multiple times within a survey flow, but the answers to the questions within the block will be overwritten each time.